# Excel VBA - remove FileDialog

Tags: excel, vba, filedialog

I am using the following code to list files in a folder.

The code works great but, I don't need the user to select the folder, the folder will be the same every time.

Can I remove the FileDialog box?

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
```

And what do I need to replace it with in order to list the files within the same folder each time?

```
Sub FolderNames()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim xPath As String
Dim xWs As Worksheet
Dim fso As Object, j As Long, folder1 As Object
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
Application.Workbooks.Add
Set xWs = Application.ActiveSheet
xWs.Cells(1, 1).Value = xPath
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array("Path", "Dir", "Name", "Date Created", "Date Last Modified")
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set folder1 = fso.getFolder(xPath)
getSubFolder folder1
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).Interior.Color = 65535
xWs.Cells(2, 1).Resize(1, 5).EntireColumn.AutoFit
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Sub getSubFolder(ByRef prntfld As Object)
Dim SubFolder As Object
Dim subfld As Object
Dim xRow As Long
For Each SubFolder In prntfld.SubFolders
    xRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row + 1
    Cells(xRow, 1).Resize(1, 5).Value = Array(SubFolder.Path, Left(SubFolder.Path, InStrRev(SubFolder.Path, "\")), SubFolder.Name, SubFolder.DateCreated, SubFolder.DateLastModified)
Next SubFolder
For Each subfld In prntfld.SubFolders
    getSubFolder subfld
Next subfld
End Sub
```

Comment: If your folder's path is static you can just set xPath to the path of your folder and remove the FileDialog related lines.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry all, think I'm being daft - I've answered my own question. 
Not sure if this is the best way but, this seems to work OK.

I replace the following;

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .Title = "Choose the folder"
    .Show
End With
On Error Resume Next
xPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1) & "\"
```

With;

```
Dim toplvl As String
toplvl = "W:\ISO 9001\INTEGRATED_PLANNING"
xPath = toplvl & "\"
```

Comment: Yes, thats the way to do it.  Alternatively remove those 3 new lines, remove the `Dim xPath`, put `Const TOPLVL As String = "W:\ISO 9001\INTEGRATED_PLANNING\"` at the very top of the the module and just use `TOPLVL` instead of `xPath`